# Java awt calculator +/- , how to replace + with - : 1st click = "-", 2nd click = "+" and so on

Tags: java, awt

[SOLVED]

I am working for Calculator application and I am stuck a little bit. For example I need to work to +/- button. How can I replace - with + for example? Just like windows Calculator does: First click = -, Second click = + and so on. 
I have some code, I used MouseListener to count clicks. I will post my if here. I work with awt, not swing yet.

```
 if(click %2 !=0)
 {
    text.setText("-"+text.getText());
 }
 else
 {
    text.setText(""+text.getText());
 }
```

`text` is object of `TextField`. If you need more details I will add parts of my code here. Thank you

Comment: You didn't mention your problem. So whats not working?

Comment: When I push +/-, I can't replace - with + just like windows Calculator does like: appear, disappear, appear, disappear

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the previous operation sign? This is your problem?

Comment: yes, I removed it but still don't work. For example when I press +/- , at first click it appear -, at second click is pause, at 3rd click it appear another -, like -- but I want that first to be removed.

Comment: Open windows calculator please, and type a number and press +/- multiple times and see what happens. That is what I want

Comment: I just posted the possible solutions, please try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if(click %2 !=0){
    text.setText("-"+text.getText());
}
else{
    // remove your first character (- sign)
    text.setText(text.getText().substring(1));
}
```

Comment: It works ! you are a genius  @cyclon ! A genius ! Thank you!